# How do I print to the stdout in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code is there to add given integer, double and concatenate the string to the user's input integer, double and string respectively.
The code is given below, but it gives no output. What's the error in it.

```
i = 4
d = 4.0
s = 'Hackerrank'
a = int(input())
b = long(input())
c = raw_input()
print(a + i)
print(b + d)
print(s+c)
```

Kindly point out the errors and let me know the reason for it not working too!

Comment: `long` and `raw_input` don't exist in Python 3.  You should get some output (`NameError` tracebacks).  Since you don't prompt for the input, you are probably staring at a blank line that is waiting for you to type something.

Comment: Your code waits for input... Maybe that's why you're not printing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hello ANIRUDH DUGGAL**

**First read this best website before start Python 3,**
1.  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/
2.  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/
3.  https://learnpythonthehardway.org/python3/

**Difference between python 2 and python 3,**
1. http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_2_3_key_diff.html
2. https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-major-differences-between-Python-2-and-Python-3

Your code perfectly works on version python 2 but if you use the Python 3 so it does not work because in Python 3 is something different syntax so first read Python 3 basic fundamentals(Syntex, inbuilt function,...etc).

**Using python2:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Using python 2
i = 4
d = 4.0
s = 'Hackerrank'

a = int(input("Enter the integer number: "))
b = long(input("Enter the long number: "))
c = str(raw_input("Enter the string: "))

print("Output1: %d" % (a + i))
print("Output1: %f" % (b + d))
print("Output1: %s" % (s+c))
```

**Using python3:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Using python 3
i = 4
d = 4.0
s = 'Hackerrank'

a = int(input("Enter the integer number: "))
b = float(input("Enter the long number: "))
c = str(input("Enter the string: "))

print("Output1: %d" % (a + i))
print("Output1: %f" % (b + d))
print("Output1: %s" % (s+c))
```

I hope my answer is useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

Consider reading https://realpython.com/learn/python-first-steps/

And to quickly check your code  use https://repl.it/languages/python3

You have several errors in your original code. here is the corrected version:

```
i = 4
d = 4.0
s = 'Hackerrank'
a = int(input())
b = float(input())
c = input()
print(a + i)
print(b + d)
print(s+c)
```

A little note: You can add a prompt to your calls to `input()` so the user knows what to type:

```
a = int(input("type int "))
b = float(input("type float "))
c = input("please type something")
```

Finally, if you want to run it with **python3** in terminal do:

```
python3 name_of_file.py
```

Comment: I have used the prompt command but, it seems to give error if the input is not enclosed in qoutes by the user, how can I fix it?

Comment: @ANIRUDHDUGGAL I think your problem is you are running python 2, and not python 3. That code works just fine in python3, without enclosed in qoutes. To run python 3, you must write python3 your_program.py. See the updated answer. And not forget accepting the answer if it was useful :)

Answer (score 0):

in python 3 it is just input() and change the long to float